# Ubuntu 12.04 installer doesn't detect Windows partitions, but I can see them in "Try Ubuntu"

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

It's the first time I am trying to install Ubuntu, and it's Ubuntu 12.04. I have got two partitions (C and D).

D is empty, while in C I have got all the files. I defragmented both and also formatted D,which has capacity for 190 GB.

The Ubuntu installer doesn't detect my main OS (Windows 7).

So I continue with the **Something Else** option, but it still doesn't detect either of my Windows partitions

[image: installation type dialog shows unpartitioned disk /dev/sda]

So instead of installing Ubuntu, I just try it, and when I open the media folder, the partitions are there:

[image: data and OS folders visible in file browser window]

OS folder is C, while DATA folder is D.

I don't want to make partitions again if there's another option, and I want to keep Win 7 also. Thanks.

This is the output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

[image: GPT partition, fdisk has some problems but detects 4 partitions, one probably NTFS]

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you've got one of two issues:

- A disk that uses motherboard-based software RAID (aka "fake RAID") and no appropriate software running in the Ubuntu installer; or leftover RAID data that's confusing the installer. You may be able to fix this problem by disabling RAID options in your firmware and/or typing `sudo dmraid -Er /dev/sda` in a Linux Terminal window. Note that this fix is risky; if the computer relies on RAID to boot and you remove the RAID data, you may no longer be able to boot.
- A damaged partition table. Your disk uses the [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) so `fdisk` will be useless for repairing it. Instead, use `gdisk`; see the [`gdisk` page on repairing partition table damage](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) for more on this topic. If you need more advice on this, post back with some basic `gdisk` output, such as the output you see when you launch it, type `p`, and type `v`.